# Error 800 connecting to VPN on certain networks on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, vpn, tcp, pptp, ipsec

I have an interesting issue trying to connect to a client's VPN on Windows 10 Pro.

I can connect to the client's VPN while connecting through my phone (4G) but not the office network however other colleagues can connect on the same network.

I have tried to reset the network adaptor, network settings, DNS with no luck. I also downloaded Wireshark to see if something pops out at me but my understanding of this networking is very limited.

The VPN settings are:

PPTP

MS-CHAP2

I'll add the information logged in the Event Viewer.

```
CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM is trying to establish a link to the Remote Access Server for the connection named VPN1 using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = hidden
Device = WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
Port = VPN2-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named VPN1 which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 800.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM has successfully established a link to the Remote Access Server using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = hidden
Device = WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
Port = VPN2-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The link to the Remote Access Server has been established by user SYSTEM.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM is trying to establish a link to the Remote Access Server for the connection named VPN1 using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = hidden
Device = WAN Miniport (SSTP)
Port = VPN1-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM is trying to establish a link to the Remote Access Server for the connection named VPN1 using the following device: 
Server address/Phone Number = hidden
Device = WAN Miniport (L2TP)
Port = VPN3-1
MediaType = VPN.

CoId={FC917C8A-C531-4137-A439-69F13747C3FF}: The user SYSTEM dialed a connection named VPN1 which has failed. The error code returned on failure is 800.
```

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days of searching the web I stumbled across this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/312840/error-message-error-720-no-ppp-control-protocols-configured which prompted me to remove and re-install the TCP protocols/protocols.

1. I went into Device Manager and removed the drivers as per the
   image below.
2. Restarted the machine
3. The drivers were reinstalled
   automatically by Windows
4. Tested the VPN.
5. All working.

[Remove these drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxvtf.png)